# docker container with multiple worker process in fastapi

Tags: docker, performance, kubernetes, deployment, fastapi

I have 2 EC2 instances with 64 GB RAM and 8 vCPUs. currently i am running one container in each EC2 instance.there is one uvicorn(fastapi)process running in the container. according to my understanding one process can handle one request at a time. I thought of using gunicorn in the container so that we can have multiple fastapi processes running , which can handle multiple requests at a time but on little bit of research, it is suggested/recommended that one container should have one process and we need to replicate/add more containers. which approach should i take like using gunicorn to have more worker processes in the same container or replicating the containers with single process

Comment: I think there are several bits of misinformation here. (1) Uvicorn is perfectly capable of handling multiple requests in parallel. There are multiple command line options for controlling the degree of concurrency. (2) The suggestion is not that a container should have one *process*, it's that a container should have a single *entrypoint*. E.g. you wouldn't run a database and a webserver in the same container, but you you *would* run a server that used multiple processes to handle connections.